# Why throws only the executable JAR a white label error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, http-status-code-404, executable-jar

I have a SpringBoot application and I used the Maven command `mvn clean package`  to create an executable jar.
My application works fine when I start it in IntelliJ but the jar which I start from cmd throws a white label error. The weird thing is that sometimes it works and when I reload or switch the HTML page the error pops up again.

This is the only error I get:

[no information where the error comes from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU5lF.png)

My Application is not in any of the subpackages and has the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`.

I used a PostgreSQL database and Bootstrap as frontend framework.

The things I tried:

- `@ComponentScan("...")`
- `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "...")`
- different WLANs
- starting without firewall
- putting all classes in one subpackage
- different JDKs
- different computers

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>at.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Testname</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My log looks like this:

````
2022-08-10 13:09:05.217 DEBUG 18536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2022-08-10 13:09:05.248 DEBUG 18536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [ServletContext [/]]
2022-08-10 13:09:05.264 DEBUG 18536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2022-08-10 13:09:05.264 DEBUG 18536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2022-08-10 13:09:05.279 DEBUG 18536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-08-10 13:09:05.279 DEBUG 18536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-08-10 13:09:05.358 DEBUG 18536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-08-10 13:09:05.374 DEBUG 18536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404```

Has anyone solved this problem or has an idea how it can be solved? 
I would also appreciate if somebody knows a simple alternative!!
````

Comment: There is far too little information. You need to check the server as to why you get the error. The client side error isn't useful. If it works on your local system it should work on the server. If it doesn't you are probably trying to access a db that isn't accessible or trying to load resource from the classpath in the wrong way (most common issues). But without seeing what your app does and the actual server side error we cannot help.

Comment: That's the thing I don't get any error on the server side nor on the db. So which information can I show you.

Comment: I doubt that you don't get information. There will be some error/logging in the logfile. Else start the app with debug logging enabled `--debug` when starting the jar and check the logs.

Comment: That's my log now

Comment: Please dont post logs/code etc. as comments they are totally unreadable, instead edit your question. But as you can see there is nothing for `/` mapped (according to the stack).